# Efficient way to convert a list of one string to a string and perform split operation

Tags: python

I have a list which contains a string shown below. I have defined `mylist` in the global space as a string using `""`.

```
mylist = ""
mylist = ["1.22.43.45"]
```

I get an execution error stating that the split operation is not possible as it is being performed on a list rather than the string.

`mylist.rsplit(".",1)[-1]`

I tried to resolve it by using the following code:

`str(mylist.rsplit(".",1)[-1]`

Is this the best way to do it? The output I want is `45`. I am splitting the string and accessing the last element. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you put your string in a list in the first place? Just do `mystring.rsplit...`

Comment: It is for the design purposes. I know I can do that but how to efficiently convert the list to a string and then do the split operation?

Comment: FYI, "defined mylist in the global space as a string" isn't a thing in python. Python is dynamically typed, and "duck-typed" so the variable can be reassigned any type at any time (as you saw when you reassigned it as a list

Comment: after your second assignment (mylist = ["1.22.43.45"]) mylist become a list! and the previous value is overwritten

Comment: You don't have anything to convert, you just built a list containing one element, which is your string. So... is your real problem something different?

Comment: For what design purposes? Can you clarify what design purpose making `mylist` a list of strings that contains only 1 string serves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mylist=["1.22.43.45"]
newstring = mylist[0].rsplit(".",1)[-1]
```

First select the element in your list then split then choose the last element in the split

Answer (score 1):

Just because you assigned `mylist = ""` first, doesn't mean it'll cast the list to a string. You've just reassigned the variable to point at a list instead of an empty string.

You can accomplish what you want using:

```
mylist = ["1.22.43.45"]

mylist[-1].rsplit('.', 1)[-1]
```

Which will get the last item from the list and try and perform a rsplit on it. Of course, this won't work if the list is empty, or if the last item in the list is not a string. You may want to wrap this in a try/except block to catch IndexError for example.

EDIT: Added the [-1] index to the end to grab the last list item from the split, since `rsplit()` returns a list, not a string. See [DrBwts' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57776322/11498682)

Comment: It should be mylist[0].rsplit('.', 1)[-1]  instead of the mylist[-1]?

Comment: If it's guaranteed that the list will always only have one string, it won't matter which one you do. [-1] will grab the last list item, [0] will grab the first. If there's only one, it won't make a difference, since the first one is also the last one. Now, if you are planning on having multiple strings in the list, you might want to modify your question a bit, since there's some additional code that would need to be added.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the first element (the string, in your case) by the index operator `[]`

```
mylist[0].rsplit(".", 1)[-1]
```